# How to run a downloaded/cloned github code in google colab?

Tags: python, github, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I have downloaded a Github code for a particular image segmentation problem, and I would like to see it executed in Colab to get an idea.

But I am not finding it easy to run it, since there are multiple .py files and functions being called across .py files. I am a beginner in this and I am finding it very difficult to solve. Can someone help me out in this regard?

Comment: Unfortunately, I fear that there is no easy solution for your problem. Multiple files complicated code is the norm for complex problems. If it was possible to solve the task in 100 lines, then, it would not be a complex problem anymore ;)

Comment: My advice : understand the method at hand (read the paper associated if any), then, try to understand the structure of the code by testing it, and with some effort you may be able to do it. If you're a complete beginner, maybe this is too high of a step for you. Try, if possible, to start with something easier.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue of importing python modules, run these commands inside your colab notebook to add these modules to the path:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/content/module_path'))
```